# redirect endless loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I'm having a problem with my wordpress site after editing the htaccess file.

This is the error I am getting from browser:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I think its kind of redirect endless loop.  Here is my .htaccess file, can anyone help?

```
RewriteEngine on 


# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteBase /
# uploaded files
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
# END WordPress
rewriterule ^index\.php$ - [L]
rewriterule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
rewriterule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
rewriterule ^ - [L]
rewriterule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with this rule, but this does not but cause a redirect loop:

```
rewriterule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin [R=301,L]
```

Original request: /foo/wp-admin

1. URI = `foo/wp-admin`
2. URI matches `^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$`, backreference $1 = `foo/`
3. Target = `foo/wp-admin`
4. Redirect browser to `foo/wp-admin`
5. repeat from step 1.

Comment: i have delete this row but it still stuck on the loop ,geting this msg 
ERROR 301 net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @user1310492 Unless you have more rules that are doing redirects, it looks like this was the only rule that was, and if you deleted it, no idea where the redirecting is coming from (it's the only rule with the **`R`** flag)